# 20 devices, each with an independent driver file. Should each have their own Git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

It seems excessive for a single file to have it's own repo, but at the same time, they are all individual projects, and completely unrelated.

Currently I have a network folder that has a "Driver Development" folder from which we copy the latest version of code to work on. And then paste it back at the end of the day.

I would like to use git.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you can't have a single git repo that holds all of your driver files. This repo could be a single folder that operates much like your existing network folder. When someone wants to make changes to a driver file they could clone the repo, make their change, and make a PR that explains their changes.

Of course, you could also make a small army of individual repos, or handle each device as a branch (don't do that), it's more important that the workflow work for you and your team than that it be consistent with how git / GitHub was "meant" to be used.

(I have no idea if this would be possible in your case, but if the code could be modularized to split out the device dependent code from the boilerplate driver code that would open up several more workflow possibilities...)

Comment: One place where people do this all the time is their personal "dotfiles" repo. This holds a variety of .bash_profile files, .vimrcs, .gitconfigs, etc, they then copy out of it the file(s) they actually need for a given machine, but make their updates to the versions kept under source control.